# Poco::Net library hangs on output of Poco::Net::SocketStream

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, port, poco-libraries

going by the slides on the [POCO website](http://pocoproject.org/documentation/index.html), I wrote a program almost identical to their first NET example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h>
#include <Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h>
#include <Poco/Net/SocketStream.h>
#include <Poco/StreamCopier.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Poco::Net::SocketAddress socket_address("www.google.com",80);
    Poco::Net::StreamSocket stream_socket(socket_address);
    Poco::Net::SocketStream socket_stream(stream_socket);

    socket_stream << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
           "Host: www.google.com\r\n"
           "\r\n";
    socket_stream.flush();

    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(socket_stream,std::cout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The CopyStream function outputs some of the data, and then hangs.
How do I get the rest of the data?

Comment: Ups, you are right. I have compiled and run the example and it hangs after two or three secons :S

Answer (score 0):

use Poco::Net::DialogSocket instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer is to call `shutdownSend()` on the socket right after the `flush()` call.

See poco issue 2384
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2384

So it would be:

socket_stream.flush();
stream_socket.shutdownSend();

Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(socket_stream,std::cout);

Answer (score -1):

Using my own TCP server to test, I see that your code hangs if it can't connect to remote server.

If there is a running TCP server, after send and receive some data to/from remote server, if I close the remote server connection (shutting down my server) the server response goes to stdout console.

Are you trying to connect with google throug a proxy?

Another clue... from Poco::Net::SocketStream description:

> When using formatted input from a SocketStream, always ensure that a
>   receive timeout is set for the socket. Otherwise your program might
>   unexpectedly hang.

Try to use a try-catch block with your code to test if it is launching some exception.

Good Luck